# Why is my Progress HUD not displaying as expected

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to develop a 'passwordless' registration form using a QRCode. The background processing works (can authenticate user), but noting happens visually until the registration is complete and the user is redirected to the apps main ViewController, however,   A progress dialog with spinner is supposed to appear during the registration process but it doesn't.  If, I manually input the credentials and press 'authenticate', everything works as expected, Just not after scanning the QR code.

Please see code below:

```
@interface ViewControllerRegister (){
    JGProgressHUD *HUD;
    NSString *regid;
    NSString *regpin;

    NSMutableDictionary *dicto;
}



//OPEN QRCODE READER VC

- (IBAction)scanAction:(id)sender
{
  if ([QRCodeReader supportsMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]]) {
    static QRCodeReaderViewController *vc = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      QRCodeReader *reader = [QRCodeReader readerWithMetadataObjectTypes:@[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];
      vc                   = [QRCodeReaderViewController readerWithCancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" codeReader:reader startScanningAtLoad:YES];
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    });
    vc.delegate = self;
    [vc setCompletionWithBlock:^(NSString *resultAsString) {
    //  NSLog(@"Completion with result: %@", resultAsString);

    }];



    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
  else {
      [self showAlert:@"Reader not supported by the current device"];
  }
}




//// PARSE THE RETURNED QR CODE DATA
#pragma mark - QRCodeReader Delegate Methods

- (void)reader:(QRCodeReaderViewController *)reader didScanResult:(NSString *)result
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    NSURL *stringfromscan = [NSURL URLWithString:result];

            dicto = [NSMutableDictionary new];

           NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:stringfromscan resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
           NSArray *queryItems = [components queryItems];



           for (NSURLQueryItem *item in queryItems)
           {
               [dicto setObject:[item value] forKey:[item name]];
           }



      if ([result rangeOfString:@"eloq"].location == NSNotFound && [result rangeOfString:@"unique"].location == NSNotFound) {

          [self showAlert:@"Looks like you've scanned an incorect QR code"];

        } else {


            self.TextViewUniqueID.text = [dicto objectForKey:@"uniqueid"];
            self.TextViewPIN.text = [dicto objectForKey:@"password"];


            double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    [self authent];

            });


        }
  }];
}





/// CREDENTIAL VALIDATION OF SORTS

- (void)authent{
      NSLog(@"s UNIQUEID %@", self.TextViewUniqueID.text);
      NSLog(@"PIN %@", self.TextViewPIN.text);
    //  [self resignFirstResponder];


      int uniqueID = [self.TextViewUniqueID.text length];
      int PIN = [self.TextViewPIN.text length];


      if (uniqueID < 7  ||  PIN < 6){


          UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                                         message:@"Your UniqueID or PIN is too short."
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

          UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Try Again" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

          [alert addAction:defaultAction];
          [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


          [self clear];

      }else{

          /*

            HUD WILL NOT DISPLAY AFTER READING QR CODE


          */ 
          HUD = [JGProgressHUD progressHUDWithStyle:JGProgressHUDStyleDark];
          HUD.textLabel.text = @"Authenticating";
          [HUD showInView:self.view];

          [self PostJson:self.TextViewUniqueID.text :self.TextViewPIN.text];

      }
}
```

Comment: Run HUD code in main thread. Of course you run the code in main queue. But there is no guarantee it will present. Use perform selector on main thread to run the code.

Comment: @phani thanks,  I tried that, it worked the first time, but will not work again.